# What is the Second mean value theorem for integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, book-recommendation, mean-value-theorem

I was attempting to solve this limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^ \infty \frac{nx \arctan(x)}{(1+x)(n^2+x^2)}dx $$

After some time I gave up and saw the solution.

The solution involves the Second mean value theorem for integrals which I never heard of.

The solution used the fact that if $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function  then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0 ^1 \frac{nf(x)}{x^2n^2+1}dx = \frac{f(0) \pi}{2}$ which is proved using the Second mean value theorem for integrals

I want to ask specifically for books that have this theorem and its proof. Because I want to see what theorem this book have that I don't know.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338175/second-mean-value-theorem-for-integrals-meaning

Comment: @GEdgar do you know a book that have this theorem ?

Answer (score 3):

Note
$$ I_n=\int_{0}^ \infty \frac{nx \arctan(x)}{(1+x)(n^2+x^2)}dx\overset{x\to nx}=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{nx \arctan(nx)}{(1+nx)(1+x^2)}dx. $$
Using
$$ \frac{nx \arctan(nx)}{(1+nx)(1+x^2)}\le\frac{\pi}{2(1+x^2)}$$
and
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\pi}{2(1+x^2)}dx<\infty $$
one has, by DCT,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=\int_{0}^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx \arctan(nx)}{(1+nx)(1+x^2)}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\pi}{2(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{\pi^2}4. $$

Comment: Isn't the substitution $x \to nx$ in the first step instead of $nx \to x$?

Comment: You are right. Thanks.